# How do you use MSBuild less than / greater than conditions?

Tags: msbuild, conditional-statements, equivalence

How do you do less than or greater than in MSBuild conditions?  I've tried the following variations both with and without single quotes surrounding the values, but no dice

`<PropertyGroup Condition="$(Var1) > 50">`

`<PropertyGroup Condition="$(Var1) &gt 50">`

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: XML entities require a semicolon.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To encode greater than use `&gt;`
To encode less than use `&lt;`

Comment: +1  Also, MSDN has a reference for MSBuild and available conditions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szfhaft.aspx

Comment: Thanks.  I saw that msbuld reference but didn't notice the semicolons at the end